# JSForce Integration with Angular Failed to compile. export 'ConnectionConfig' was not found in './connection'

Tags: javascript, angular, salesforce, jsforce

I have recently started using angular and I want to do an integration with jsforce. My problem is that when I try to call some jsforce method the following message appears ->

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./node_modules/jsforce/browser/core.js 14:0-185 "export
> 'ConnectionConfig' was not found in './connection'

[Image of above error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRqBQ.png)

I tried to include in the class

```js
import jsforce from 'jsforce';
import { config } from 'process';
```

But it still does not work. I hope you can help me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It would help if you added a little more of the code you are using (unless the import statements really are your entire code base). Having a minimal example of what is required to reproduce the error will help people help you better. Also creating that example often leads people to discover the error on their own.